# Horizontal and vertical scrollview in a UITableview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to add horizontal scroll and vertical scroll in a single UITableview.

Like this,
[image]

I tried my level best but I doesn't get solution. Can anyone please help me out here.

All solutions are appreciated.

Comment: I tried my level best but I doesn't get solution. can you show Code

Comment: My code is totally wrong and i deleted it. Do you have any suggestion please?

Comment: 1st Row of tableViewCell  take  another collection view or TableView according your need. Main tableView having Vertical Scrolling and your inside collection/tableview Scroll Horizontal..

Comment: Default table view dosen't support horizontal scroll. You can use a scrollview or a collection view inside one of the cells of the tableview to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any way to create UIScrollview as a custom cell and add it on the 1st row? Will it works?

Comment: do you need vertical scrollview for each cell or how

Comment: For indexpath.row  == 0 create a new custom cell which contain paging and rest of the tableviewcell use your normal cell. try it it will work

Comment: @Uday.M vertical scrolling for each cell except 1st one.

Comment: @Sommm Exactly what i'm looking for. Do you have any relevant code? It will be very useful for me.

Comment: another way is create two section. in first section set custom cell with paging  and other way with  normal tableview cell. Google out Paging.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can do this..
For that you need to add `scrollView` inside each cell and resize their content size so that it can scroll horizontally.
Let me show you briefly how could you do this..

If You are using using AutoLayouts you should insert a UIScrollView in the ContentView of TableView Cell and give them Constraints `(.Top .Trailing .Bottom .Leading)` and all of these constraints have `constant = 0`.

Then add an other `UIView` inside this view and set the same constraints that you have set for `scrollView`. This will show you red colour constraints indicating that these constraints are ambiguous but dnt worry just control draw your cursor form this view to the parentView of Scroll View and set equal width and equal height. when you finish this please change the `priority of equal width constraint from 1000 to 720`.
Now final add you actual content view in the above `UIView` and insert what ever you want to insert in this View it may be extends beyond the boundary of its parent View. When finish adding the object just put the constraints like above mentioned `(.Top .Trailing .Bottom .Leading)` with same constants but this time you should also provide the width constraint as well.

This width constraint will actually act as a constraint height. You can change the size later by making this width constraint as IBOutLet and then resize scrollContent width programatically.

For good practice you should create a `CustomClass` for your `TableViewCell`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add scroll at each cell.

You need to create custom cell with **UICollectionView** inside put **delegate, datasource** from your controller.
Then implement **UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDatasource** methods in controller.
To recognize which cell currently showing create property in cell class, for example **tableViewIndexPath** which you can set in **tableView willDisplay Cell**.
I think its help you.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for me as your requirement.Please try this.

```
#pragma mark -- Table view delegate and datasource --
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return 10;

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *cellid = @"cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
        self.tblHistory.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.tblHistory.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        UIScrollView *scrollViewFood = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 44)];

        scrollViewFood.pagingEnabled = YES;
        UILabel *lblFood;
        NSInteger numberOfFoods = arrFoods.count;
        CGFloat xOrigin = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFoods; i++) {
            NSString *strNames = [arrFoods objectAtIndex:i];
            CGSize textSize=[strNames sizeWithAttributes:
                             @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]}];
            xOrigin = CGRectGetMaxX(lblFood.frame);
            lblFood = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, textSize.width + 10, 44)];
            lblFood.text = strNames;
            lblFood.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
            lblFood.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            lblFood.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [scrollViewFood addSubview:lblFood];
        }

        scrollViewFood.contentSize = CGSizeMake(lblFood.frame.size.width + xOrigin + 10,44);
        scrollViewFood.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollViewFood.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollViewFood.delegate=self ;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollViewFood];

    }else if (indexPath.row == 2){
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 44)];
         scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cell.frame.size.width , 100);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];

    }

    return cell;

}
```

You change height,width of label as your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding with UITableView scrolling you can follow this two links

[horizontally table scrolling](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)

[vertically table scrolling](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

i hope it helps you for better understanding and make familiar with UITableViewDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Create a custom scrollView by subclassing it and just put below code in there. In Storyboard or whatever, use this custom scrollView class. Then TableView and Scroll View would scroll simultaneously. You need to do this because ScrollView's gestureRecognizer delegate CANNOT be accessed from your ViewController, it must be obtained from from ScrollView class itself by subclassing it.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```